# How can I write a function that both input and output is a std::variant

Tags: c++, c++17, variant

I want to write a function that both input and output are variants.

```
VariantTypeA GetA(const VariantTypeB& b) {
  return std::visit(MyVisitor(), b);
}
```

But I got a exception saying that 
std::visit` requires the visitor to have a single return type.

How can I write a function like that? Can I use switch instead? How?

Comment: Seems like this answer might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56039676/490790

Comment: Can you show us how `MyVisitor` is defined?

Comment: In C++20 you will be able to specify `VariantTypeA` as [a template parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) of `std::visit`

Comment: As @xandox suggested, I returned VariantTypeA in my visitor instead of different return types.

Answer (score 1):

Use a visitor with return type `VariantTypeA`.

Comment: May not work if `VariantTypeB` has duplicate types that has to be reflected in the result `VariantTypeA`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `std::variant` and letting the visitor deduce the element doesn't work if the variant has duplicate alternative types.  Here's a function template `variant_visit` that preserves the `index()` of the variant. `variant_visit` also sets the corresponding alternative type in the result variant to `std::monostate` if the visitor returns `void` for some argument, because `std::variant` with `void` is ill-formed.  SFINAE is omitted for simplicity.

```
namespace detail {
    template <typename T>
    using wrap_void_t = std::conditional_t<std::is_void_v<T>, std::monostate, T>;

    template <typename Variant, typename Func,
              typename = std::make_index_sequence<std::variant_size_v<
                  std::remove_reference_t<Variant>
              >>>
    struct result_variant;
    template <typename Variant, typename Func, std::size_t... Is>
    struct result_variant<Variant, Func, std::index_sequence<Is...>> {
        using type = std::variant<
            wrap_void_t<
                std::invoke_result_t<
                    Func,
                    decltype(std::get<Is>(std::declval<Variant>()))
                >
            > ...
        >;
    };
    template <typename Variant, typename Func>
    using result_variant_t = typename result_variant<Variant, Func>::type;

    template <typename Variant, typename Visitor, std::size_t... Is>
    auto variant_visit(Variant&& variant, Visitor&& visitor, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    {
        using Ret = result_variant_t<Variant, Visitor>;
        using fp_t = Ret (*)(Variant&&, Visitor&&);
        const fp_t fp_array[] = {
            [](Variant&&, Visitor&&) -> Ret { throw std::bad_variant_access{}; },
            [](Variant&& variant, Visitor&& visitor) -> Ret {
                if constexpr (std::is_same_v<std::variant_alternative_t<Is, Ret>,
                                             std::monostate>) {
                    std::invoke(std::forward<Visitor>(visitor),
                                std::get<Is>(std::forward<Variant>(variant)));
                    return Ret(std::in_place_index<Is>);
                } else {
                    return Ret(
                        std::in_place_index<Is>,
                        std::invoke(std::forward<Visitor>(visitor),
                                    std::get<Is>(std::forward<Variant>(variant)))
                    );
                }
            } ...
        };
        auto fp = fp_array[static_cast<std::size_t>(variant.index() + 1)];
        return fp(std::forward<Variant>(variant), std::forward<Visitor>(visitor));
    }
}

template <typename Variant, typename Visitor>
auto variant_visit(Variant&& variant, Visitor&& visitor)
{
    return detail::variant_visit(
        std::forward<Variant>(variant),
        std::forward<Visitor>(visitor),
        std::make_index_sequence<
            std::variant_size_v<std::remove_reference_t<Variant>>
        >{}
    );
}
```

Usage example:

```
int main()
{
    {
        std::variant<int, int, double> var{std::in_place_index<1>, 10};
        auto result = variant_visit(var, std::negate{});
        std::cout << std::get<1>(result) << '\n';
    }
    {
        std::variant<int, int, double> var{std::in_place_index<2>, 2e20};
        auto result = variant_visit(var, std::negate{});
        std::cout << std::get<2>(result) << '\n';
    }
    {
        std::variant<std::unique_ptr<int>> var{std::make_unique<int>(30)};
        auto result = variant_visit(var, [](auto& ptr) { return -*ptr; });
        std::cout << std::get<0>(result) << '\n';
    }
    {
        auto inspector = [](auto&& ptr) {
            if constexpr (std::is_const_v<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(ptr)>>) {
                std::cout << "const";
            }
            if constexpr (std::is_lvalue_reference_v<decltype(ptr)>) {
                std::cout << "&\n";
            } else {
                std::cout << "&&\n";
            }
        };

        std::variant<std::unique_ptr<int>> var{std::make_unique<int>(30)};
        variant_visit(var, inspector);
        variant_visit(std::as_const(var), inspector);
        variant_visit(std::move(var), inspector);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
-10
-2e+20
-30
&
const&
&&
```

([live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/uCPra7IFi2VY4EgO))

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by simply wrapping the visitor in a lambda that performs the conversion back to a variant:

```
template <class Visitor, class Variant>
auto variant_visit(Visitor &&visitor, Variant &&variant) {
    return std::visit(
        [&](auto &&in) -> std::remove_reference_t<Variant> {
            return visitor(static_cast<decltype(in)>(in));
        },
        std::forward<Variant>(variant)
    );
}
```

[See it live on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/KyeKKyqzVxb0PRgU)

Comment: Won't compile with `std::variant<int, int, double>`.  The conversion is ambiguous.

Comment: @L.F. damn, I was wondering why you went the long way around... Well, no point in me duplicating your work then.

Comment: Well, looking back at my answer I can't believe I wrote unintelligible stuff like that :)